# How can i switch to root from ad login to send ssh keys to /root/.ssh/authorized-keys

Tags: linux, ssh, shell-script, ssh-keys, authorized-keys

I am trying to send ssh keys to multiple servers from jump server using shell script. I can only login from my ad account and then switch to root and cannot login directly as root. Having this condition how can i send ssh keys to servers that needs to be copied under /root/.ssh/authorized-keys?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to be root on the jump server in order to access other servers as root.

First establish an ssh config file if you don't already have one. It usually exists in `~/.ssh/config`  (where ~ is shorthand for $HOME).

Some things you'll need to know first are the IP ranges of the servers you're trying to get to from the jump server. Hopefully those IPs are not in the same subnet as the jump server.

Here's a sample:

```
# save as ~/.ssh/config
CheckHostIP             no
StrictHostKeyChecking   no
AddKeysToAgent          yes
ForwardAgent            yes
UserKnownHostsFile      /dev/null

# Servers to get to via jump server
# (note their subnet defined by a range using an asterisk, you need to provide)
# This establishes root as login id for every server in the range 
# and uses the JumpServer (can leave that name as is) as a proxy.
Host                    192.168.122.*
    ProxyJump           JumpServer
    User                root

# JumpServer info. Provide its IP or FQDN and your user id
# IP or FQDN set in the HostName; you can leave Host set as JumpServer
# since this is referred to above in ProxyJump line
Host                    JumpServer
    HostName            ip-or-fqdn-of-jumpserver
    User                your-user-id
```

Only 3 things need changing by you for your environment in the above sample:

- replace `192.168.122.*` with your server IP range
- replace `ip-or-fqdn-of-jumpserver` with your jump server IP or FQDN (fully qualified domain name)
- replace `your-user-id` with your user id on the jump server used to ssh into it

Once that file is created, you can put the public key in root authorized_keys file for every server via the `ssh-copy-id` command shown below. The first time of course you may need to provide credentials.

*Also, by default, most servers are configured to disallow ssh root access directly. If that's the case you have more sshd_config changes to make on each server.*

Now simply run `ssh-copy-id 192.168.122.10` to copy your public key to roots authorized_keys file on a server. Of course replace the IP with your own server IP. Repeat for each server.

Once the key is present on each server, you now ought to be able to `ssh some-server-IP` and a connection will automatically be made to the jump server using your user id, and port forwardings established in order to access the remote server as root.